# Should the site be "Ubuntu Specific"?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we tell if a question belongs here, or rather at stackoverflow/superuser?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser)

I got a down vote on this issue for a question that is not "specific to Ubuntu".

I believe that an Ubuntu user should ask/answer everything here and not to research what is specific to Ubuntu and what is not (Ubuntu is, after all, a Linux distribution). 
He/She will know that here everything WORKS on Ubuntu, could not care less what parts of the question/answer is specific to Ubuntu and what is not.

There will be some overlap with Serverfault, and possibly other Linux stack exchange sites, but otherwise if we will try to nail "Ubuntu specific" in questions and answers, it will probably lead to a knowledge split and a usability nightmare. It should be one place.

Comment: This issue is already being discussed here:

http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser

Comment: thanks, it is the same discussion