# Should Ubuntu server questions be allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Or should we focus on desktop and servers should go on ServerFault?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorry to ask back: Shall we close Ubuntu and the Desktop users go to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?

And now serious: I think Ubuntu server is a part of the Ubuntu universum, there are as well Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu studio, Ubuntu netbook remix, Ubuntu privacy remix, ...

Comment: Touché. I suppose you have a point.

Answer (score 8):

Question about Ubuntu servers are certainly not off-topic, since Ubuntu is one of the Ubuntu flavors. That does not mean they would be off-topic on serverfault, especially if they are general. Some overlap is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the same basic issue as [How do we tell if a question belongs here, or rather at stackoverflow/superuser?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser)

It simply depends on the question.

Any basic question where the answer involves pointing the user to /*etc/apache2/sites-{available,enabled}/* or */etc/apache2/mods-{available,enabled}/* certainly feels relevant for this site. On the other hand, to continue with an Apache example, a question comparing the benefits of different MPM:s (prefork, worker, etc) might do better at Server Fault.

Answer (score -2):

I would say that if it is specifically about ubuntu server then yes. If we want to be a better community we should answer more. So people would come to Ask Ubuntu as a first resource.