# Is "any tool that runs on Ubuntu" on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

That's the response I got to a flag I raised about a `git` question which had already been answered on StackOverflow a few years earlier.

Git runs on Ubuntu as well as on Windows or Mac, so it could be asked on AskDifferent or SuperUser, but I doubt it would be welcome there more than on SO.

Anyway, if we really allow questions about "any tool that runs on Ubuntu", that's opening a can of worms. People could ask questions about, I don't know, Slack, because [it has an app that runs on Ubuntu](https://slack.com/downloads/linux).

Comment: Yes, and questions about running slack on Ubuntu are absolutely on topic. There is basically _nothing_ that is specific and exclusive to Ubuntu.

Comment: I think this is the exact same point as the one discussed in the duplicate. Please let me know if you disagree or feel that I closed incorrectly.

Answer (score 7):

I think [the “What topics can I ask about here?” help page](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) is quite clear about that:

> Questions that you may ask:
>   …
>   Running third-party applications on
>   Ubuntu.

This obviously includes `git` as well as Slack, and this is a good thing IMO. Installing and using e.g. Slack on Windows is quite different from doing the same on Ubuntu, so a platform for Ubuntu-related questions about it is needed. There are certainly questions here which are the same for other systems, but in the majority of cases nobody can be sure this is actually the case – and if it is, it still doesn’t really hurt to have the question on AU. It’s not worth the trouble to filter them out.